# Pandas groupby with MultiIndex columns and different levels

Tags: pandas

I want to do a groupby on a MultiIndex dataframe, counting the occurrences for each column for every `user2` in `df`:

```
>>> df
      user1 user2 count
                   0             1      2
                   a      x      d      a 
    0  2     6     0      1      0      0
    1  4     6     0      0      0      3
    2  21    76    2      0      1      0
    3  5     18    0      0      0      0
```

Note that `user1` and `user2` are at the same level as `count` (side effect of merging).

*Desired output*:

```
  user2 count
        0              1      2
        a       x      d      a 
0  6    0       1      0      1
1  76   1       0      0      0    
3  18   0       0      0      0
```

I've tried

```
>>> df.groupby(['user2','count'])
```

but I get

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'count' not 1-dimensional
```

GENERATOR CODE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user1':[2,4,21,21],'user2':[6,6,76,76],'param1':[0,2,0,1],'param2':['x','a','a','d'],'count':[1,3,2,1]}, columns=['user1','user2','param1','param2','count'])
df = df.set_index(['user1','user2','param1','param2'])
df = df.unstack([2,3]).sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user1':[2,5,21],'user2':[6,18,76]})
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, [''],['']])
final_df = df2.merge(df, on=['user1','user2'], how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Comment: why is your data like that? count having levels I mean

Comment: @Yuca it's a product of merging a dataframe with MultiIndex columns and a regular dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
final_df.where(final_df>0).groupby('user2').count().drop('user1', axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  user2 count         
            0     1  2
            a  x  d  a
0     6     0  1  0  1
1    18     0  0  0  0
2    76     1  0  1  0
```

Avoid dropping columns, select only 'count', and changed function to `sum`:

```
final_df.where(final_df>0).groupby('user2').sum()[['count']].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  user2 count               
            0         1    2
            a    x    d    a
0     6   0.0  1.0  0.0  3.0
1    18   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2    76   2.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

To void dropping user2 equal to zero values also.

`final_df[['count']].where(final_df[['count']]>0)\
                    .groupby(final_df.user2).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks, Scott, this works! I can also replace `count` with any other function like `sum`. However, is there a workaround to manually dropping the other columns? In the full dataframe (this is a sample one), there are many columns that I want to drop and I prefer not to write them down one by one.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Also, here's another snippet that uses the `agg` function based on what you wrote: `final_df.where(final_df>0).groupby('user2').agg(fxn)[['count']].reset_index()`. That could be helpful for some people.

Comment: There's also a problem with this approach. If one of the `user2` values is 0, then `.where(final_df>0)` will automatically exclude that row. I tried using `.where(final_df['count'] > 0)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `f2 = final_df.set_index(['user1','user2'])` `f2.where(f2>0).groupby('user2').sum()[['count']].reset_index()`

Comment: OR `final_df[['count']].where(final_df[['count']]>0).groupby(final_df.user2).sum().reset_index()`